# Compute Sum : $\sum_{n＝1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n}\Big(\frac {\ln(n)}{n－\ln(n)}\Big)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Compute Sum : $\sum_{n＝1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n}\Big(\frac {\ln(n)}{n－\ln(n)}\Big)$

This problem is from the book :[Book proplem analysis I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821820508) 

proplem 3.1.5 (b)


The solution from the book: [image]

My question: What exactly did he do?  How did he get S=0?  I appreciate the community's interest.

Comment: Obviously the sum is greater than $0$, so something is wrong. Either: a) $S$ doesn't mean the sum of the series; b) you have copied the text over from the book incorrectly; c) the book is wrong.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comment.  I copied the text of the question incorrectly. I thought this symbol meant the parentheses [] and it meant floor x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the book, the sum is written as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \left[\frac{\ln n}{n - \ln n}\right].$$ Sometimes, square brackets are used as an alternative to parentheses. However, in this case, they have a different meaning: $[x]$ is used to denote the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $x$, or the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. (See the "Notation and Terminology" section at the beginning, which defines $[x]$ as "the integral part of a real number $x$".)

These days, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is usually used to denote the floor of $x$, rather than $[x]$, but this is a book published in 2000. Maybe the notation wasn't as common back then, or maybe typesetting $\lfloor x\rfloor$ was a pain. (As a possible point of comparison, the [ARML math competition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Regions_Mathematics_League) used $[x]$ for the floor as late as 2007, but switched to $\lfloor x\rfloor$ by 2010.)

In any case, once we read $\left[\frac{\ln n}{n - \ln n}\right]$ as the floor of $\frac{\ln n}{n - \ln n}$, the problem becomes easy for exactly the reason written in the solutions: for all positive integers $n$, we have $0 \le \frac{\ln n}{n \ln n}  < 1$ , which means that $\left[\frac{\ln n}{n - \ln n}\right] = 0$, and the sum is $0$ because every term of the sum is $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought he meant [] in parentheses. Thank you for clarifying the matter